# Why does search not find questions I know are there?

Tags: support, search

I wanted to find submissions containing the terms "rails", "mysql" and "bluehost". I found this one via Google:
 [Rails 3.2.13 app fails after shared host Mysql update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231209/rails-3-2-13-app-fails-after-shared-host-mysql-update)
But when I try to search SO directly , I can't even find the one I found through Google. I tried adding "body:" before "bluehost" since this appears only in the body. But it still doesn't find this one submission.
I really want to figure this out, since I am having a difficult connection problem between Mysql and Rails on Bluehost.

Comment: Because google indexes pages but SO search indexes posts. The only mention of Bluehost is in the answer and that has "bluehost" and "mysql" but not "rails".